# Passar valores de um Objeto para outro form C#

Tags: c#

Tenho um sistema, onde após o usuário fazer login, eu puxo de um XML vários dados sobre ele e guardo em atributos de um objeto, porém existe um outro form para fazer a alteração de senha ,onde eu necessito do User_ID do primeiro form... Como eu consigo passar valores de um objeto para outro form no c#? Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, acredito que variáveis globais são a solução para isso:

```
public class Main
{ 
    public static string User_ID { get; set; }
}
```

uma variável public static(global) pode ser chamada em outros forms da aplicação com o nome da classe e seu nome:

```
Main.User_ID
```

para mais detalhes pesquise sobre tipos globais.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma propriedade do tipo da sua classe no formulário que deseja receber o objeto e passar o objeto no construtor dor formulário, veja um exemplo abaixo.

Formulario que vai receber o objeto:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private User user;

    public Form2(User user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

E o formulário que vai enviar o objeto para o formulário que ele esta chamando:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = new User
        {
            User_ID = 1,
            Name = "Fulano",
            Email = "exemplo@mail.com"
        };

        var form = new Form2(user);            
        form.Show();            
    }
}
```

Desta forma você pode manipular os valores do seu objeto dentro do formulário sem qualquer tipo de interferência.